# Looking for guidance: autocomplete within a sentence triggered by "@" symbol

Tags: jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I've found plenty of instructions on how to use JQuery to perform an autocorrect for a textbox or drop down. However, it's not quite meeting my needs.

Here's what I'd like:

A user starts to type the following in a text box:
"I wanted to thank Kelly @K" at which point I'd like to see an inline dropdown show up to recommend all of the handles which start with @K. Then, the user could select @KellyAnderson from the list which would populate the text box with "I wanted to thank Kelly @KellyAnderson" with the cursor at the far right ready to continue typing the sentence. The dropdown would be triggered with the typing of the "@" symbol.

I don't have code as I'm stabbing in the dark for this.

Thanks in advance,
Rob

Comment: Well, Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service, so we're not going to build the plugin, and SO doesn't handle researching a plugin for you either. I'd do a search for "jquery suggestion plugin". If you're trying to write or integrate the plugin and are stuck at a certain point, then we can help with that.

Comment: I've enjoyed SO's community for providing guidance based upon their broad experience. As you would expect, I searched for what I thought I wanted but wasn't making progress. I was hoping for an experienced hand to provide direction, not code. Fortunately, I found the following link after looking at several of the Related posts to the lower right: http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-autocomplete/page/4/. This seems to do the trick.